# How to run the QR code encoder sample code?

Tags: xcode, qr-code, encoder

I tried to run the QR code encoder example in
https://github.com/myang-git/QR-Code-Encoder-for-Objective-C

but it could only be built. The run button is always gray.
I've google this problem. Somebody said it's because executable is missing.
I tried to go to "product->edits scheme" and try to give the path of executable, but i cannot give the path because there is no executable.

Does anybody ever try this example?

Answer (score 0):

The files you downloaded is just a library, there are no executables. You need to write your own interface and implementation that includes the library for it to be executed in the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I added and commit an executable target for a demo app. You can check out the latest code from the repository and see how it works.